# Does a Python registry have to contain both source and wheel files?

Tags: python, package

I'm running a private, self-hosted Python registry.

My question is: Do both the source archive (.tar.gz) *and* wheel (.whl) files have to be present in the registry for `pip` to be able to install the package? Or just one or the other? If both are present, are both somehow used in the installation or is one chosen over the other?